# Showing warning tree in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have multiple files opened in my Xcode project in different Xcode editor windows.

I also have an actual Xcode project window.

If I have a compilation/linking error(s), those error(s) are showing in the currently displayed editor window, which may not necessary be a project window in addition to the project window.

Is it possible to redirect this pane to be opened inside the project window ONLY?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has a feature known as Behaviors. You can set these up in Xcode -> Settings -> Behaviors.

It sounds like you want something similar to my own setup. I have some Behaviors setup such that builds always appear in a special tab. I do the same for debugging and searching. This way my editing stays in one tab, builds in a 2nd tab, debugging in a 3rd tab, and searching in a 4th tab. Of course you can setup whatever you wish.

Here are screenshots under Xcode -> Settings -> Behaviors -> Build that ensure that a tab named Build is always used for build results/output.

First, I don't have anything setup under Build -> Starts

Here is Build -> Generates new issues:

[image]

Here is Build -> Succeeds:

[image]

Here is Build -> Fails:

[image]

Obviously you can adjust these to suit your own needs. It's a handy, little known feature.

Comment: how is you Xcode set up? in My case I don't have many tabs - I have new Windows open. So I have a Windows for a project, then a Window for header1.h and Window for header2.h. Then I have a Window source1.cpp and a Window for source3.cpp. So for my project I have 5 Windows opened and not just 1. Now when I run the build I have all errors/warnings to display on the current active Window (the one I'm currently editing), which is not necessary a project Window.

Comment: So - I'm not talking about TABS inside a project Window, I'm talking about multiple editor Window that can be opened when I double click on the file in the project source tree.

Comment: I only have one window per project. Within that window I have a tab for editing (which in turn shows separate sub-tabs for each open file), a tab for debugging, etc. I just looked and under Xcode -> Preferences -> Navigation, I have several settings configured for tabs. If you want lots of separate windows, then follow the screenshots in my answer but for each "Show" checkbox, select "window" instead of "window tab".

Comment: @HangarRush, it's not a matter of preference. If you double click the file - it will open in a new window instead of tab. And it is useful, especially if you want to check the code on some other file while editing. Problem is- if I need to compile. Then warning/error tree will show up in the currently active editor instead of the project window and it be shown completely expanded.

Comment: *"it's not a matter of preference. If you double click the file - it will open in a new window instead of tab.*" - it *is* a preference. When I double-click a file it does open it in a new sub-tab of my current window tab. I do not get another window. *"if I need to compile. Then warning/error tree will show up in the currently active editor instead of the project window"* - not if you follow the steps in my answer (but choose "window" instead of "window tab".